# Cakephp 3 Image Upload - Validation not working

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, file-upload

Cakephp 3 - Image upload handling is currently too complex.

I'm working on a WIN7 System with XAMPPv3.2.2

I have this test view - Clients\file.ctp for testing uploads

```
<div>
<?= $this->Form->create($client, ['type' => 'file']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('logo', ['type' => 'file']); ?>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

I upload an image named logo (successfully) to the server via this controller - ClientsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Filesystem\Folder;

class ClientsController extends AppController
{
public function file() {
    $client = $this->Clients->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->log($client, 'debug');
        $this->log($this->request->data, 'debug');

        $client = $this->Clients->patchEntity($client, $this->request->data);
        // Here my first error was included - I have setup the model including LOGO as a varchar(250) field. 
        // This is transferred into a text field but the upload needs to be an array
        // How do we have to define an image field within the Database?
        if (!empty($this->request->data) && !empty($this->request->data['logo']) && !empty($this->request->data['logo']['name']))
            $client->logo = $this->request->data['logo'];

        // Assigning test  to see if something is saved within the DB
        $client->name = 'TEST';              

        if ($this->Clients->save($client)) {
            $this->log($client, 'debug');
            $this->log($this->request->data, 'debug');

            $this->Flash->success(__('The client has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'file']);
        } else {
            //debug($client->errors());
            $this->Flash->error(__('The client could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }

    $this->set(compact('client'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['client']);
}
```

Question 1:
I have had to assign the uploaded array on myself to the model variable that it works and gets uploaded. How should the database model look like to get an image upload generated via BAKE? I could not find this documented.

I have setup following ClientsTable.php to get this data validated

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Model\Table;

 use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
 use Cake\ORM\Table;
 use Cake\Validation\Validator;

 class ClientsTable extends Table
 {
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('clients');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    // I handle the upload of the image within this Behavior.
    // This is working well! This validator is triggered with beforeSave event
    $this->addBehavior('Upload', [
        'field' => 'logo',
        'uploadPath' => 'logos',
        'setUniqueGuidName' => true
    ]);
}

public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->uuid('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->allowEmpty('title');

    $validator
        ->add('logo', [
            'uploadError' => [
                'rule' => 'uploadError',
                'message' => 'The cover image upload failed.',
                'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
            ],

            'mimeType' => [
                'rule' => array('mimeType', array('image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg')),
                'message' => 'Please only upload images (gif, png, jpg).',
                'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
            ],
            'fileSize' => [
                'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '1MB'),
                'message' => 'Cover image must be less than 1MB.',
                'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
            ],
        ])
        ->allowEmpty('logo');
    }
}
```

Question 2: Why is the validation not triggered? I can upload PDF files and also files which are bigger than 1MB and get always a successful message. I can also find the documents uploaded in the directory! With files which are bigger than 1MB i get an interesting exception

```
2016-02-25 03:17:07 Error: [RuntimeException] Cannot validate mimetype for a missing file
Request URL: /pam/clients/file
Referer URL: http://localhost/pam/clients/file
Stack Trace:
#0 [internal function]: Cake\Validation\Validation::mimeType(Array, Array)
#1 C:\Users\D052192\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\pam\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Validation\RulesProvider.php(71): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(NULL, Array)
#2 [internal function]: Cake\Validation\RulesProvider->__call('mimeType', Array)
#3 [internal function]: Cake\Validation\RulesProvider->mimeType(Array, Array, Array)
#4 C:\Users\D052192\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\pam\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Validation\ValidationRule.php(138): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 C:\Users\D052192\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\pam\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Validation\Validator.php(1410): Cake\Validation\ValidationRule->process(Array, Array, Array)
#6 C:\Users\D052192\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\pam\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Validation\Validator.php(137): Cake\Validation\Validator->_processRules('logo', Object(Cake\Validation\ValidationSet), Array, true)
#7 C:\Users\D052192\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\pam\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Marshaller.php(193): Cake\Validation\Validator->errors(Array, true)
#8 C:\Users\D052192\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\pam\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Marshaller.php(466): Cake\ORM\Marshaller->_validate(Array, Array, true)
#9 C:\Users\D052192\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\pam\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Table.php(2073): Cake\ORM\Marshaller->merge(Object(App\Model\Entity\Client), Array, Array)
#10 C:\Users\D052192\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\pam\src\Controller\ClientsController.php(102): Cake\ORM\Table->patchEntity(Object(App\Model\Entity\Client), Array)
#11 [internal function]: App\Controller\ClientsController->file()
#12 C:\Users\D052192\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\pam\vendor\friendsofcake\crud\src\Controller\ControllerTrait.php(51): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#13 C:\Users\D052192\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\pam\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Dispatcher.php(114): App\Controller\AppController->invokeAction()
#14 C:\Users\D052192\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\pam\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Dispatcher.php(87): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\ClientsController))
#15 C:\Users\D052192\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\pam\webroot\index.php(37): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#16 {main}
```

Here is the output of the two log entries from the controller

```
 2016-02-25 03:36:36 Debug: {
"logo": "C:\\Users\\D052192\\OneDrive\\xampp\\htdocs\\pam\\webroot\\img\\logos\\56ce76c3edb88.pdf",
"name": "TEST",
"created": "2016-02-25T03:36:35+0000",
"modified": "2016-02-25T03:36:35+0000",
"id": "6d84cf0c-a1b9-4c1b-8e61-98dce6b9a659"
 }

2016-02-25 03:36:36 Debug: Array
(
[logo] => Array
    (
        [name] => TK.pdf
        [type] => application/pdf
        [tmp_name] => C:\Users\D052192\OneDrive\xampp\tmp\php57F0.tmp
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 6437
    )
)
```

I have searched a lot via google and also within the documents but could not find out if i have an issue with the setup of the validation call it self or with the assignment of the logo variable.

I have logged the flow within CakeCore - Validation.php.

First i call uploadErrors wich is executed without error response if i upload a PDF file.
Second is the mimeType Check which gets following values

```
public static function mimeType($check, $mimeTypes = [])
$check = Array
        (
            [name] => TK.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [tmp_name] => C:\Users\D052192\OneDrive\xampp\tmp\phpB7C.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 6437
        )

$mimeTypes = Array
        (
            [0] => image/gif
            [1] => image/png
            [2] => image/jpg
            [3] => image/jpeg
        )
```

Together with these values this function returns FALSE. 
So the question is, why is this false not processed? 
Where should i look next?

Comment: The problem might be with the upload behavior, it must be fiddling with the data somehow at some point, as otherwise using the actual field name for upload would cause the file array to be marshalled into an empty string.

Comment: i have disabled the behavior completely within the table model. It is not called now but the same problem still exists. Is the validation called after the behavior? I thought the first thing what gets called is validation.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are referring to by "_called_", but behaviors can listen to events like any other object, so it could listen to the `Model.beforeMarshal` event, which occours before validation. However, in case you are receiving the very same exception with the behavior not being loaded, then that specific problem may be caused by something else, maybe there's some kind of race condition, a permission problem, etc... all I can do from here is shooting in the dark.

Comment: I'd suggest to do some debugging, starting with the cores validation methods to check what data exactly they receive, and whether the file is properly accessible at that point. Also it wouldn't hurt if you'd show the behavior code, maybe there actually is a problem, and you're just receiving a similar error with the behavior not in use.

Comment: I have deleted the cache and now i got another exception.

So you're right, within the behavior I copy the file and assigned the new filename back to the var. `$logo`

Comment: The new exception is: 

`2016-02-25 12:58:54 Error: [InvalidArgumentException] Cannot convert value to string`

This exception is caused by this line:

`if (!empty($this->request->data) && !empty($this->request->data['logo']) && !empty($this->request->data['logo']['name']))
            $client->logo = $this->request->data['logo'];`

**What do i have to assign to the file value to get the validation working as it should be? The array of the uploaded file?** Currently the behavior is still commented and i only want to block the form from starting processing the file as it is a PDF...

Comment: The `logo` property finally needs to hold a string, most probably the path or filename of the uploaded file. However, the mentioned line has nothing to do with validation, which will happen earlier when using `Table::patchEntitiy()`.

Comment: I have done some debugging (see extended description), with the core validation method to check what data exactly they receive, and whether the file is properly or not. For my surprise, the function returned FALSE as it should be (as PDF is not in the list of valid mimeTypes). Why could this be ignored? Why is the upload not blocked? Any further idea?

Comment: I guess this is because assigning a value to an entity property causes it to be marked as dirty, which in turn unsets possible errors for that specific field, ie assiging data to `$client->logo` clears the possible validation errors. **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.2.3/src/Datasource/EntityTrait.php#L641**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ndm ***Thanks a lot for all your hints!*** You're right! With this call

`$client = $this->Clients->patchEntity($client, $this->request->data);`

the data is validated and only set if, the validation was positive.
Setting the `$logo` to the value within the request, cleared the validation status and therefor was not shown on the screen. I have commented this out

`if (!empty($this->request->data) 
  && !empty($this->request->data['logo']) 
  && !empty($this->request->data['logo']['name']))
          $client->logo = $this->request->data['logo'];`

But in that case, if i transfer a valid image, the `$client->logo = ""` is empty. If i transfer an invalid image, the `$client->logo` is not set at all.

So i solved my issue with extending the if-statement as follow

`if (!is_null($client->logo) 
    && !empty($this->request->data) 
    && !empty($this->request->data['logo']) 
    && !empty($this->request->data['logo']['name']))
          $client->logo = $this->request->data['logo'];`

I set the `$logo` only if the validation was accepted and set before. ***The final question is only, why `$client->logo = ""` is empty if a valid image was transferred and has to be assigned manually.***

Answer (score 0):

I see that the column name in your database, where you store the path of image is also named **logo**. So, try changing the input name from **logo** to something else in your **view** followed by making changes in **controller** and **table** as well.